# How to call function in my dll from jquery

Tags: jquery, vb.net, dll

My question is simple, I want to call a function in my **dll** via jquery.

I'm trying the following

> $(window).load(function () {
>
> ```
>    $.ajax({
>        type: "POST",
>        url: "RemotePaymentdll/Class1/CheckPending",
>        data: '{}',
>        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>        dataType: "json",
>        success: alert("Success"),
>        error: alert("Error")
>    })
> ```
>
> });

the function in my dll is the following

> ```
> Public Shared Sub CheckPending()
>     Dim aaa = ""
>
> End Sub
> ```

I just want to be able to access `CheckPending()` in my `dll` from jquery. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using an HttpHandler to do the server side work, you can call it via javascript:

You could create an .ashx file with some code a bit like this:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="MyTestHandler" %>
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Xml

    Public Class MyTestHandler : Implements IHttpHandler


        Private ReadOnly Property Parameter1() As Integer
            Get
                If Not IsNothing(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("Parameter1")) Then
                    Return CInt(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("Parameter1"))
                Else
                    Return -1
                End If
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
            context.Response.Clear()
            context.Response.Buffer = True
            context.Response.Expires = -1
            context.Response.Write("YOUR OUTPUT HERE")
            context.Response.Flush()
            context.Response.End()
        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
            Get
                Return False
            End Get
        End Property

    End Class
```

Comment: But can i update my webform controls in this httphandler? is it possible in anyway?

Comment: I'm glad you found that useful. You could set session variables in the handler and use some sort of update panel to refresh the control values, or you could send the values via the handler output and inspect the output in the JavaScript and update your controls..

Comment: HttpHandlers are very useful for interacting with server side .net code from JavaScript, however you have to assess the risks of them being exploited and implement a security mechanism if necessary

Answer (score 1):

Normally, JS can only access local resources plus URL resources.

I suggest that create a Resuful API at server side to call the CheckPending method.
and JQuery consumes this API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
   var ObjFromDll = new ActiveXObject("RemotePaymentdll.Class1"),
       result = ObjFromDll.CheckPending();
});
```

This will only works in IE...

If you have problems to instantiate the `ActiveXObject` have look [here](http://www.aras.com/Community/forums/p/2527/7698.aspx)